# Does the XBOX 360 controller have pressure sensitive buttons

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I am reliving my childhood today with the fantastic Metal Gear Solid HD Collection, and I have noticed that the buttons on my XBOX 360 controller(unlike the buttons on my old Playstation 2 controller) don't seem to be pressure sensitive. This is making aiming my Rifle a nightmare, as I'm either not holding it, or I am shooting bullets everywhere!

I think even the original DualShock controller that came out for the original Playstation had pressure sensitive buttons. Does the XBOX 360 controller not have pressure sensitive buttons? Or has the game just been badly ported from the PS2?

Comment: It was actually the DualShock 2 for PS2 that added pressure sensitive face buttons, if I recall.

Comment: @agent86 apologies, you are correct!

Comment: Weird, this is literally the first I've heard about pressure sensitive face buttons on controllers.  Probably because I owned a PS1 and a Xbox 360; but never a PS2 or original Xbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Xbox 360 controller does not have pressure sensitive face buttons.  The only pressure sensitive inputs are the analog sticks and the triggers.  The issues this causes for games developed for other platforms is a common complaint - notably Metal Gear Solid games, as you've mentioned.

Wikipedia even mentions this in their article about [gamepads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamepad):

> [On the Xbox 360 controller,] the pressure-sensitivity feature on the face buttons was removed, making some original Xbox games, such as Metal Gear Solid 2, unplayable.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty damn lame.

Comment: @BenBrocka, yeah, I guess you could say the Metal Gear experience...  isn't very *solid.*  *shades*

Comment: I seem to remember a teardown of the original xbox 360 controller questioning why the pressure sensitive contacts were under the d-pad and not the 4 main face buttons. They suggested that it was a design mistake and not a design decision. As the d-pad did not have pressure sensitive implementation in the games that were out, and the original xbox had pressure sensitive buttons. However, that was just speculation, and I cannot find the 7 year-old article now. :/

Answer (score 2):

Decided to answer my own question 6 years and 6 months later, as this game has just been re-released on XBOX One via backwards compatibility!

It turns out you can click the left analogue stick to raise/lower your weapon in first person view.

- Click once in first person view to raise active weapon
- While raised, press X to fire
- Click again to lower active weapon
- If active weapon is raised by holding down X, click once to lower it

Answer (score 0):

MGS2 was ported the original Xbox and its controllers buttons were pressure sensitive but since very few games used it when It was time to make the 360 Microsoft removed it. So the 360 does NOT have pressure sensitive buttons like its predecessor.